# Подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от асинхронности при загрузке данных с firestore database,

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-database

Подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от асинхронности при загрузке данных с firestore database.

А еще при попытке подсчета количество записей (`lenLessonNum`), и вывод этого значения в цикле `for (data in it.documents`) показывает почему последнюю цифру только 5 ,даже если записей больше 5-ти.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnPostClickListener {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var lenLessonNum = 0
    private lateinit var myDB: FirebaseFirestore

    val posts = ArrayList<Post>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.actvity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.course)

        // recyclerView для перечисления курсов
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            MarginItemDecoration(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin))
        )
        myDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        myDB.collection("LESSON").document("class").collection("8").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (!it.isEmpty) {
                    for (data in it.documents) {
                        lenLessonNum++
                    }
                    getPostList()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               }
            }
           .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ploho", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    private fun getPostList() {
        myDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        for (i in 1..lenLessonNum) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            myDB.collection("LESSON").document("class")
                .collection("8").document(i.toString()).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {

                    posts.add(Post("${it.get("name_lesson")}", 50))
                    recyclerView.adapter = PostsAdapter(posts, this)
                               }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ploho", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
    }
}
Происходит чтение название тем и создается список recycleview. Который представляют собой карточку в которой есть и текст и две кнопки. Проблема в том, что при каждом запуске при нажатие на кнопку в cardview, происходит действие которое соответствует этой карточки(её номеру), но вот название тем никак не соответствует номеру карточки. Обнаружил, что в этой части private fun getPostList() { myDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() for (i in 1..lenLessonNum) { i не начинается с 1. а вообще с произвольной цифры 
[![Скрин пути к документу выглядит вот так:] [1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUj7Y.png
```

Comment: От асинхронности вы никак не избавитесь - сетевой запрос нельзя выполнять в UI потоке. И скорее всего вам это и не нужно. Опишите подробнее чего вы пытаетесь добиться и что не так сейчас - пока ваша проблема не понятна.

Comment: Происходит чтение название тем и создается список recycleview. Который представляют собой карточку в которой есть и текст и две кнопки. Проблема в том, что при  каждом запуске при нажатие на кнопку в cardview,  происходит действие которое соответствует этой карточки(её номеру), но вот название тем никак не соответствует номеру карточки. Обнаружил, что  в этой части    private fun getPostList() {
        myDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        for (i in 1..lenLessonNum) {   **i**  не начинается с 1. а вообще с произвольной цифры

Comment: Подробности нужно добавлять в вопрос: [edit]. Зачем вы дважды запрашиваете одну ту же коллекцию, сначала целиком, потом по одному элементу? Вы можете заполнить свой список в том цикле, где вы считаете количество элементов, а следом за циклом создать и прикрепить адаптер. Если нужна какая-то последовательность элементов - просто отсортируйте список перед созданием адаптера.

Comment: Прикрепил слайд с firestore. Проблема в том, что получается мне надо перебрать документы (у которых имена в виде цифр) в котором содержится коллекция с названием и ссылкой. Спасибо Вам за помощь. Если возможно конечно перебирать документы в коллекции. И потом залазить внутрь каждого документа, то было проще конечно. но как это сделать правильно у меня не получается, хотя вроде искал информацию. Конечно в идеале запихать формирование адаптера в splash screen, но опять непонятно как распознать все ли данные получены, если не известна их количество заранее. еще раз спасибо за информацию

Comment: Сделал как вы писали. Просто залез во внутрь каждого элемента и выкинул расчет длины. Все спасибо. Получилось